# Override Bootstrap form template in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Symfony 2.8

I'm trying to override some blocks of bootstrap themes for forms. 
Particularly interested the block "form_label_class" in the theme "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig":

```
{% block form_label_class -%}
    col-sm-2
{%- endblock form_label_class %}
```

I created the file my_form.html.twig and inherited it from "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig":

```
{% use "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block form_start -%}
...
{% endblock form_start -%}

{% block form_label_class -%}
    {{ width_test }}
{%- endblock form_label_class %}
```

Also added the definition of "width_test" in the form class:

```
....

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['width_test'] = $options['width_test'];
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('width_test', 3);
}
```

The problem: as a result of getting the error:

> Variable "width_test" does not exist in form/my_form.html.twig

Importantly, "width_test" is not defined only in the block "form_label_class", but no problems to display it for example  in the block "form_start"